# Set an element in an arraylist of a specific class

Tags: java, arraylist

In my program I have a pair class:

```
class Pair {
  public int ind = 0;
  public String letter = "";
  public Pair(int a, String b) {
    ind = a; //index
    letter = b;
  }
}
```

how do I set the index (ind) of an element in an arraylist of Pairs? I have tried

```
RightMotor.ind.set(j, i);
```

and

```
LeftMotor.set(j, i).ind;
```

but they don't seem to work.

Comment: LeftMotor and RightMotor are my arraylist of pairs

Comment: For future reference you need to include a bit more of the code than what you have provided. It is better to provide more than not enough. However, I do believe you have your answer below.

Comment: Please review [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) as variables should not start with a capital letter. `RightMotor` should be `rightMotor` and `LeftMotor` should be `leftMotor`. This will make it easier for others to read and quickly understand your code.

Comment: I wanted to post something about that but you beat me to it. Likewise I did post an answer that I think that you were trying to accomplish... but once again this is open to interpretation since you did not provide enough code here

Answer (score 1):

First you need to 'get' the Pair instance, like:

```
Pair pair = LeftMotor.get(i);
```

then you can change its fields:

```
pair.ind = j;
```

This can also be done in one line:

```
LeftMotor.get(i).ind = j;
```

Hint 1: this is **not** changing the index (position) of the instance in the list, `LeftMotor.get(i)` will still return the same element. `i` and `ind` are two completely disjunct values.

Hint 2: normally it is better to have private fields and have a method (setter) to change the fields (encapsulation):

```
class Pair {
  private int ind = 0;
  private String letter = "";
  public Pair(int a, String b) {
    ind = a; //index
    letter = b;
  }
  public void setInd(int newInd) {
    ind = newInd;
  }
}
```

Hint 3: just to be clear, just because it is called `ind` it is *not* the index (position) of the list. It is a whole different question if you want to change the order of the elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make those instance variables private, then getters/setters to access/modify them. This allows you to safely and securely manipulate the data with a reduced chance of bleedover (which can crash your program or cause unintended consequences).

Within your class:

```
class Pair {
  private int ind = 0;
  private String letter = "";

  public Pair(int index, String letter) {
    ind = index; 
    letter = letter;
  }

  public int getIndex() {
      return index;
  }

  public void setIndex(int index) {
      this.index = index;
  }

  public String getLetter() {
      return this.letter;
  }

  public void setLetter(String letter) {
      this.letter = letter;
  }

  public void setIndexAndLetter(int index, String letter) {
      this.index = index;
      this.letter = letter;
  }

}
```

Elsewhere in your program:

```
Pair rightMotor = new Pair(1, "a");
Pair leftMotor = new Pair(2, "b");
Pair middleMotor = new Pair(0, "");

rightMotor.setInd(3);
leftMotor.setLetter("d");
middleMotor.setIndAndLetter(rightMotor.getInd() + leftMotor.getInd(), "z");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `Pair` instance using the `Pair` constructor before adding it to the `ArrayList`:

```
RightMotor.add(new Pair(i,j)); // assuming i is an int and j is a String
```

If you want to replace the `Pair` stored in a given index use:

```
RightMotor.set(index,new Pair(i,j));
```

If you want to change an existing `Pair` stored in the `ArrayList`:

```
RightMotor.get(index).setInd(newValue);
```

This will require a setter method in your `Pair` class:

```
public void setInd (int i) {
    ind = i;
}
```

Comment: @Frank in that case, use RightMotor.set(index,new Pair(i,j));

Comment: is there a way to just edit the int, thanks? thanks for your help btw

Comment: Main.java:307: error: cannot find symbol
      LeftMotor.get(j).setInd(i);

Comment: @Frank you have to add a `setInt(int i)` method to your `Pair` class.

Comment: i found the answer: LeftMotor.get(j).ind = i;

Comment: @Frank It's not a good idea to update instance variables from outside the class. It breaks encapsulation. The instance variables should be private and only modified via method calls.

Answer (score 0):

So I think that you could solve this in a couple of different ways... however I think I know what you are trying to do.... I feel like you are trying to keep the ArrayList and the Pair index synchronized... either way you will need a helper method to accomplish this. I agree with hendripd that you should use private variables and utilize the getters and setters. However this is my solution.

Pair:

```
public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {

    private int index = 0;
    private String letter = "";

    public Pair(int index, String letter) {
        this.index = index;
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public Pair(Pair pair) {
        this.index = pair.getIndex();
        this.letter = pair.getLetter();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair pair) {
        if (this.index > pair.index) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.index < pair.index) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.index + " " + this.letter;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }

    public String getLetter() {
        return this.letter;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public void setLetter(String letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {
    public static ArrayList<Pair> rightMotor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rightMotor = new ArrayList<Pair>();

        rightMotor.add(new Pair(0, "a"));
        rightMotor.add(new Pair(1, "b"));

        setIndex(rightMotor, 0, 1);
        // If you choose to go with the second option utilizing Comparable<Pair>
        // Collections.sort(rightMotor);

        for (Pair pair : rightMotor) {
            System.out.println(pair.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void setIndex(ArrayList<Pair> motor, int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        Pair tempPair = new Pair(motor.get(oldIndex));
        if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            for (int i = oldIndex; i < newIndex; i++) {
                motor.set(i, motor.get(i + 1));
                motor.get(i).setIndex(i);
            }
        } else if (oldIndex > newIndex) {
            for (int i = oldIndex; i > newIndex; i--) {
                motor.set(i, motor.get(i - 1));
                motor.get(i).setIndex(i);
            }
        }
        tempPair.setIndex(newIndex);
        motor.set(newIndex, tempPair);
    }
}
```

Note that the Pair class implements comparable... you could use Collections.Sort(rightMotor) which then you would only need to fix the indexes of the instances... i.e.

```
public static void setIndex(ArrayList<Pair> motor, int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    motor.get(oldIndex).setIndex(newIndex);
    if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
        for (int i = oldIndex; i < newIndex; i++) {
            motor.get(i + 1).setIndex(i);
        }
    } else if (oldIndex > newIndex) {
        for (int i = oldIndex; i > newIndex; i--) {
            motor.get(i - 1).setIndex(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Or... you can use the original one I posted which also handles the sorting at the same time. This keeps your Arraylist in numerical order by index either way.

Test casing:

```
    rightMotor.add(new Pair(0, "a"));
    rightMotor.add(new Pair(1, "b"));
    rightMotor.add(new Pair(2, "c"));
    rightMotor.add(new Pair(3, "d"));
    rightMotor.add(new Pair(4, "e"));
    rightMotor.add(new Pair(5, "f"));

    setIndex(rightMotor, 0, 1);
    setIndex(rightMotor, 3, 1);
    setIndex(rightMotor, 4, 3);
```

outputs this result:

```
0 b
1 d
2 a
3 e
4 c
5 f
```